# Why are C++ template calculations so fast?

Tags: c++, templates

I wonder about the next code.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
template<int N> struct Fib {
    enum { v = Fib<N - 1>::v + Fib<N - 2>::v };
};
template<> struct Fib<0> {
    enum { v = 0 };
};
template<> struct Fib<1> {
    enum { v = 1 };
};
int fib(int n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
int main() {
    cout << Fib<46>::v << '\n';
//    cout << fib(46) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

It calculates the result at the compilation time without any noticeable delay.  How is it possible?  If we use the call to fib(46) we will have to wait for several seconds even with the fastest PC.  The template uses the same schema of calculation and it makes it instantly.  I am also surprised by the fact that the size of the executable file produced with the template is almost the same as without template. I used GCC.

Comment: "without any noticeable delay." - how did you measure it?

Comment: time g++ fib.cpp -o fib

Comment: i have serious doubts about your measurements. If you have to wait for several seconds to get the result at runtime you either didnt turn on optimizations or did something else wrong. Also its quite uncommon to have "no noticeable delay" when doing compile time calculation

Comment: Templates are evaluated in compile time, not at run time. You basically move the calculations to compilation, so it's longer compilation and shorter execution. Also, naive recursive approach works alright with templates (each value is only evaluated once), but at runtime it's pretty bad, at it has to reevaluate each value several times.

Comment: time ./fib   I can assure you that my measurements are ok.
@Yksisarvinen thank you but the compilation time almost didn't change. So I can assume that GCC uses some trick to do calculations with templates.

Comment: This is not a lot of calculations. It's generation of 45 classes, which all have one enum only. Simple task for modern compilers. In runtime (if no optimizations are applied by compiler - I have no knowledge about those), you have to calculate each fibonacchi value 2^(n-i) (where i is the value). And 2^44 calculations for fib(2) is quite bad perspective.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's due to inherent *[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)* in the template solution.

During compilation, each instantiation like `Fib<1>`, `Fib<2>`, etc, is performed (by the compiler) only once and remembered.

When you run `fib(n)` on the other hand, `fib(1)`, `fib(2)`, etc. are calculated many times. The solution could be to *memoize* it, i.e. remember the result of each `fib` call in a map or an array, and return that if a result already exists.

Comment: would be right to say that memoization here is done by compiler, not by resulting program. Each Fib<N> is instantiated only once

Comment: @rustyx, where are the previous calculated values stored if this is done during compilation?

Comment: @codekaizer - the values are stored in memory in the generated instantiations of the `Fib` template (the enum `Fib<N>::v`).

Answer (score 1):

They are not fast, they are already there.
If you manage to write such a template program the value that you're using will be there before the program starts.
This can be also achieved with `constexpr`.
However, the fact that you need all the information at compile time is making it
applicable to a very few use cases.

I've reworked your example to show you that([link to example](https://godbolt.org/g/5jVKP5)).

```
main:
.LFB0:
  .file 1 "/tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler118417-63-1cf1gj5.e1tp/example.cpp"
  .loc 1 12 0
  .cfi_startproc
  .loc 1 14 0
  mov eax, 1836311903
  ret
```

The `eax` is filled with the number `1836311903` which happens to be exactly the 46th fibonnaci number.

Comment: Does not answer OP's question. The OP wrote: "It calculates the result at the compilation time without any noticeable delay.". The question was: "why doesn't it take longer to **compile**?", not "why doesn't it take longer to execute?"

Comment: @GoranFlegar tbh , question formulated in such way that it isn't clear. I also actually would question it, because in single thread template and constexpr variants compile time is  almost 10 second. I assume that template instance generation and constexpr resolving are parallelized

Answer (score 0):

`fib()` is a recursive function which is bad for performance in this case, because of multiple iterations of function call and stack creation.

Template value would be calculate value statically, because N is known at compile time. Also try:

```
constexpr int fib(int n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

This would make it equivalent of template solution, value of function would be calculated in compile time if possible)
with -O2 flag :P

Comment: I am using GCC version 6.3.0 and -O2 doesn't affect the time for this case, the program runs several seconds for fib(46),

Comment: @vollitwr with `constexpr`? I doubt it, I tested it, though on v.7

Comment: Thanks! constexpr changes things much.

Comment: Not sure that with constexpr function, memoization has to take place...

Comment: @Jarod42 it doesn't. Compiler just unfolds that function. `fib(1)` becomes  `const int <something> = 1` etc,  and so on.

Comment: How many times `fib(1)` is "computed" (at compile time) ? whereas with template, I know it is only one, for `constexpr`, I would have said as many as usage.

Comment: @Jarod42 once within single compilation unit, memoization of constants here at work too

Comment: clang has difficulty with the `constexpr` function [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9bf693a9a71e846) but not with template struct [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23131f91a84519bb). (gcc is fine with both).

Comment: @Jarod42 This is only conjective, but there were known instances where clang attempts to go deeper into optimizing out loops and recursions by finding end-of-iteration values, heuristic may take longer? i.e. it tries to unfold it as a non-recursive function first. gcc avoids that kind optimization, because it may result in creating more expensive operations.